# Click button in ng-repeat to post id to php and update mysql entry

Tags: php, angularjs

I have an angular app which gets questions,answers, and explanations from a mysql DB. The goal is to have a button associated with each returned Q and A which will allow that question and answer to be updated/modified in the database.

A search box shows relevant results with ng-repeat in the index.html:

```
<html ng-app="test">
<body ng-controller="QSearch">
...
<div class="container">
<div ng-repeat="item in testAccounts | filter:searchText">
<div ng-if="card_index == $index && card_index != -1">
<br/> This is question number <span class="badge">  {{item.num}} </span>
 <button class = "btn btn-danger" ng-click="modify(item.num);">Modify</button>
<div class="text-primary">
<h4>{{item.question}}</h4></div>
<div class="text-danger" ng-show="showAns" >
<h4>{{item.answer}}</h4> </div></div>
</div>
</div>
....
angular.module('test', ['ui']).controller('QSearch', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.modify = function (itemID) { alert(itemID);
    $http.post(update.php, {id: itemID})
};
};
```

The alert box correctly pops up with the id of the question - my problem is how to call the update.php file with this id - the aforementioned does not work.

The update.php file:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$link = mysql_pconnect($host, $username, $password) or die('Could not connect');
mysql_select_db($database, $link);
$id2 = $_POST['id'];
$query ="SELECT question, answer, discussion FROM expert WHERE idx='$id2';";
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $link);
$result = mysql_query($query, $link);
```

I also tried json_decoding the input to the update.php file (a fail):

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$id = $request->id;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is your update.php in root of your server app?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "update.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "id": itemID })
});
```

Comment: Thanks. update.php is in the same directory as the file calling it. The above did not work either, unfortunately.

Comment: can you use fiddler or postman to see what is sent in the request? @CLS

Comment: Sorry, no idea how to do that